# Where output of Bash itself goes?

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, file-descriptors

For one script I wanted to redirect "[1] 00000" message that appears my shell after `sleep 100&` command. I don't need that anymore, but while struggling with that problem, I start thinking: there output of Bash itself goes? Why `bash > test`, `bash &> test` or `bash | [some program]` don't work? 1 and 2 file descriptor are only ones that will be write to terminal, right? So, how bash or any other program can bypass stdout if them want to be printed to user?

Comment: "_Why `bash > test`, `bash &> test` [...] don't work?_" - they do work: both start a shell and write its output+error to a file. Perhaps what would be better is for you to describe what you think they should do

Comment: What are you trying to do? bash is not special with regard file descriptors. It looks like you have a different problem that you are attributing to file descriptors. Explain what problem you are trying to solve. Give examples, give expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 1):

That message is just sent to stderr, but it's *bash's* stderr, not the stderr of the command, so redirecting output & error of the command doesn't affect it.

To illustrate this, you can redirect stderr for a command group to redirect that message:

```
$ { sleep 100& } 2>test
$ more test
[1] 94358
$ 
$ 
$ # Then, 100 seconds later:
[1]+  Done                    sleep 100
$
```

If you don't want status messages like "Done" (and you're in a context where they'd normally be shown), you can `disown` the background job:

```
$ { sleep 10& disown $!; } 2>test
$ more test
[1] 94400
$ 
$ # After 10 seconds:
$
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that (job messages goes to the shell) and that's why I investigated bash. My question is, where bash output goes and why e.g. `bash 2> file` doesn't do anything? Thanks for your answers though, but could you update it to corresponding my questions?

Comment: Just curious, why "[1]+  Done                    sleep 100" doesn't go to test file?

Comment: @Basher But `bash 2> file` *does* do something. If you run that interactively, you'll get another shell that 1) doesn't prompt (since it's not in interactive mode), 2) won't print backgrounding/job status messages at all (again because it's not interactive), and 3) will send its error/status messages to the file rather than the terminal. How exactly are you testing it? I think you may be misunderstanding something. As for why the "Done" message doesn't go to the file, it's because it's printed by bash *after* (and hence outside of) the redirected `{ }` command group.

Comment: Your question was answered but you ignored the answer.  The output in question goes to stderr, but is not part of the command whose stderr was redirected.  If you redirect the output from bash itself rather than the command, it is saved to a file.  Note also that this specific output is saved to the bash variable `$!`

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are interacting with is called job control. It is based on API functions standardized by POSIX.

Job control is organized around a terminal session. The job control shell, in this case Bash, is the "traffic cop" of the session. It controls which process groups is in the job control foreground and which are in the background.  That same shell also arranges all the indirections when you use syntax like `>`, `<` and `|`. When the shell wants to output something into the terminal, it can easily do so, since it is the boss.

When some command is running in the foreground, the shell puts itself into the background. During those moments it is quiet. The shell puts informational messages when it it in the foreground.
For instance, when you issue a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to a program currently in the foreground, you will see a message like:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 vi
```

Before that message is printed, Bash first puts that program into the background, and puts itself into the foreground. It then "holds the TTY stick": it can obtain input from the terminal and write to the terminal. That's when it prints the informational job-control-related message.

These messages from the shell itself are not captured by redirections. When we type `command > file &` the `[1] nnnnn` message indicating that Job 1 is running in the background and has pid `nnnnn` does not go into `file`. That would not make sense. The shell arranged that `> file` redirection for that `command` only; the shell itself holds the file descriptor of the terminal and sends the `[1] ...` message to that.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but that isn't my question. My question is, why `bash &> file` doesn't work? As far as I know, outputs of all programs go stdout (file descriptor 1) or stderr (file descriptor 2) and them can point to output devices or not if redirection. How bash can override this?

Comment: @Basher Some programs explicitly open the `/dev/tty` device to gain access to the terminal, even though their standard input and output are redirected. For instance, to ask the user for a password. Or to display progress. I made an interactive program called [PipeWatch](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about/) that lets you monitor data passing through it; it can be used in a pipeline (both input and output redirected), but gives you a full screen display with interactive commands.

Comment: Okay and every program can do that if it want? Override whole standard streams? Does Bash do that (write directly to /dev/tty)?

Comment: Because the `[1] 00000` (where 00000 is a pid), did not come from the program.

Comment: Do not tell us it did not work. Tell us what you expected, and what you got.

Comment: @Basher Yes, every program can open `/dev/tty` to gain access to the terminal, if it is in a terminal session. The `[1] 0000` is printed by Bash's job control code. Job control code is related to a terminal. It does not make sense to send that message to a standard output that might not be the controlling terminal.  If you want to know what exact system calls a program makes, try `strace -o program.log program ....`, then inspect the `program.log` trace.